# Determine if increasing sequence $\sup_n u_n = u \in \mathcal{L}^1$

Tags: measure-theory

In my homework, I am trying to determine for an increasing sequence $(u_n)_{n=1}^\infty \in \mathcal{L}^1(\mu)$ then $\sup_n u_n = u \in \mathcal{L}^1(\mu)$

My intuition is that this is true. Because if all $u_n \in \mathcal{L}^1$ then also $\sup_n u_n=u \in \mathcal{L}^1$

However I am not sure how to prove this mathematically.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true.

Take in $[0,+\infty]$ with the Lebesgue measure, the sequence $u_n=1_{[0,n]}$

$u_n$ is increasing and $\sup_nu_n=1_{[0,+\infty]}$

Answer (score 1):

$I_{(0,n)}$ is increasing each of these function is integrable w.r.t. Lebesge measure. But the limit or supremum  is $I_(0,\infty)$ which is not integrable.

Comment: If I add the condition $sup_n \int u_n \, d\mu < \infty$ do we then have $u \in\mathcal{L}^1$?

Comment: Yes, in that case $u$ is integrable.

Comment: Is it because you use u as a dominating function for $|u_n|\leq u$ and then set $sup_n \int u_n d\mu =\int sup_n  u_n d\mu =\int u \, d\mu$?

Comment: You can use Monotone convergence theorem of fatou's lemma. DCT cannot be used here.

Comment: You have to consider $u_n-u_1$ for above method to work.